# Inserting values into mysql database with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I need to insert username and password values into a database with qt creator and no two username should be the same. After doing that check I should proceed with the insertion. When I run my code below I don't get any changes in my database. I cant seem to find the problem and am clueless as how to proceed. Is there any way I can improve my code?

```
void LoginScreen::createClicked()
{
    QString username{ui -> newUsernameInput -> text()};
    QString password{ui -> newPasswordInput -> text()};

    QString command{"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + '\''};
    QSqlQuery query(db);

    bool ok{query.exec(command)};

    if(ok)
    {
        while(query.next())
        {
            QString newUsername{query.value("username").toString()};

            if(username == newUsername)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Username already exists!");
                ui -> newUsernameInput -> clear();
                ui -> newPasswordInput -> clear();
            }
            else
            {
                QString insertCommand{"INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('"
                           + username + "', '" + password + "');"};
                QSqlQuery quer(db);
                query.exec(insertCommand);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the username doesn't exist in the database this statement will be false:

```
while(query.next())
```

i.e. no records are returned.

You're building strings for queries but it's better to use prepared queries instead. Not only will it take care of special characters in the username and password but protect against injection attacks too. I would restructure your code like this:

```
void LoginScreen::createClicked()
{
    QString username{ui -> newUsernameInput -> text()};
    QString password{ui -> newPasswordInput -> text()};

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    query.bindValue(":username", username);
    bool ok{query.exec()};

    if(ok)
    {
        if (query.next())
        {
            QString newUsername{query.value("username").toString()};

            if(username == newUsername)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Username already exists!");
                ui -> newUsernameInput -> clear();
                ui -> newPasswordInput -> clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            QSqlQuery query(db);
            query.prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(:username,:password)");
            query.bindValue(":username", username);
            query.bindValue(":password", password);
            query.exec();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

There's no need to for this check:

```
if(username == newUsername)
```

because you know that a username already exists in the database by the time you get to this point.